# Customize the storage configuration retrieval

Tags: 2013, configuration, broker

In our current setup, we install the Deployer as a Java application on our OTAP servers. The T and P environments both have Staging and Live targets. Our infrastructure is setup in such a way that the filesystem storage locations in Staging differ from the filesystem storage locations in Live. This could be solved by using separate Deployers for Staging and Live, but we would prefer to be able to deploy the same application package for the Deployer to both Staging and Live instead.

In light of the above, I was wondering if it is possible to influence the (used location of the) cd_storage_conf.xml configuration as used by the Broker? I could envision a solution like on of the following:

1. Package 2 versions of cd_storage_conf.xml, for Staging and Live. By using our own Java code in the Storage config retrieval process, we could then decide – based on some environment/JNDI setting – which cd_storage_conf.xml to use.
2. Or package 1 version of the cd_storage_conf.xml, but inside it use some placeholder for (part of) the filesystem locations. By using our own Java code in the Storage config retrieval process, we could then resolve – based on some environment/JNDI setting – the value of the placeholder.

Or maybe some other solution might be possible?

Comment: Do you want to have one application processing both staging and live deployment requests? Or is it one installation package for both? It is important to realize that the difference between staging and live is more than just the filesystem location of the webapplication...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you actually want to change which storage_conf to use based on data contained in the package itself. Given that Tridion loads and caches all its configuration at startup, this won't be possible.

**CORRECTION**

After I actually understood, what you seem to want to do is to bind some of these variables to a runtime value (for instance, define the filesystem location as ${root}). This is not possible for FS locations unfortunately. For database info you can use JNDI configuration settings, but not for the FileSystem.

Comment: Hi Nuno, not sure I understand your remark "contained in the package". What I would like is to be able to decide, using custom Java code, and based on some container/environment setting/property, which cd_storage_conf.xml Tridion will load/use, both at Deploy time (when publishing), as well as at request-time (when an application handles an http request). Can I in some way do this by overruling the default cd_storage_confsteps.xml in cd_datalayer with my own XML? In that case I could specify my custom Java class to process the configuration that's loaded.

Comment: OK, what you want to be able to keep the same is the application deployment package - we don't support using variables in the configuration files, you'd have to do the replacement as part of your deployment process.